# Remove "Switched to mobile data" notification on Samsung devices

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S9. How do I get rid of notifications when the phone does not see a known Wi-Fi and switches to mobile data?

Answer (score -1):

Open Settings app >Tap Connections >Press and hold Wi-Fi >Tap ADVANCED>Toggle the Smart Switch

Comment: If I open settings, tap connections, tap Wi-Fi (no difference if I hold it), via the three dots tap advanced, I find no smart network switch. Although to the screenshot at https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/what-is-smart-network-switching/ shows that setting, I have "Switch to mobile data" and "Turn on Wi-Fi automatically".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because the point is not to switch the _setting_ off, but rather just to switch the _notification_ off.